# is there a standalone sed-like tool than can load whole file into memory, perform multiline regex on it and stdout it?

Tags: regex, windows, sed, multiline

I know I can use any of the scripting languages for it that is perl, python etc... but this means that I must install big package with all its dependencies while I need only regex feature and second I want it to be fast and portable, that is only regex engine and sdt streams compiled into the application, nothing more. Is there anything like it ?

Comment: [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html)?

Comment: There must be `awk` for MSWin somewhere, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is program that does exactly what I was looking for:

https://sites.google.com/site/regexreplace/ - rxrepl, Regular Expression Search and Replace Command Line Tool, Version 1.3

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about using:

- [Sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) part of the GnuWin package
- or [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) which also includes Sed

Both are light and fast. Both have dependencies but light ones.

Answer (score 0):

vbscript and powershell have native regex function and is part of windows dependeing version of it.

Answer (score 0):

> but this means that I must install big package with all its dependencies

How big is the package (binaries on 64bit Windows), used space on HDD:

```
Perl    109 MiB This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread (ActiveState)
php      48 MiB PHP 5.5.5 (cli) (built: Oct 15 2013 11:47:27)
Python   48 MiB Python 3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 18 2013, 21:19:30) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```